# Toggle node on "space" hotkey but not on "mouseclick"

Tags: javascript, jstree

To toggle node with both "mouseclick" and "space" I just wrote :

```
  .bind("select_node.jstree", function (event, data) {
       $("#tree").jstree("toggle_node", data.rslt.obj);
    })
```

but what if I just need to toggle only on "space" hotkey and not on "mouseclick".

Comment: Do you use hotkey and UI plugins? Can you provide full code of jstree definition? The best would be if you can provide jsfiddle sample.

Comment: Here it is http://jsfiddle.net/ydzyuban/G789k/30/ But nodes toggle when you use "space" key and when you "mouseclick" on them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use hotkyes plugin http://jsfiddle.net/radek/G789k/31/

- added hotkeys definition

  ```
  hotkeys: {
       "space" : function (e, n) {
                 var node = this._get_node(this.data.ui.hovered);
                 $("#jstree").jstree("toggle_node",node);
       }
  }
  ```
- I removed your bind